# Git pull error libcurl.so.3 not found

Tags: php, git, curl

I have a php script to `git pull` from my github repository set up in my webservice hook urls like so:

```
<?php
  echo shell_exec('~/git/usr/bin/git pull 2>&1');
?>
```

When I open this script on the browser, I get this error:

```
git-remote-https: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am on a godaddy server running CentOS release 5.9 and `uname -mrs` yields:

```
Linux 2.6.18-348.3.1.el5PAE i686
```

When I tried doing :

```
yum install curl
```

I get an error that the command `yum` cannot be found.

I seriously have no idea what's going on here because when I ssh into my server and do `git pull` from the terminal or run the script like `php myscript.php`, it works fine and all the changes are fetched. How are the dependencies changed when I run it in the browser?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libcurl3`

Comment: I am on centOS as I mentioned and commands like `sudo` and `apt-get` can't be used. Also. because I am on a godaddy shared hosting I don't exactly have the permissions for everything. Thanks again

Comment: The script is not running `git pull`, like you said you do in the terminal.  Instead, it's looking for the **git** directory in the "user"'s home directory `echo shell_exec('~/git/usr/bin/git pull`.  Additionally, the PHP script might be executed as different users, depending on your web server's configuration.  So, `~` might not be what you expect.

Comment: As for the `yum` command missing, this is from within your terminal? If so, there might be some `cPanel` crap hiding the yum command, or a way to use their scripts to install libcurl.  Either way, you're far from using a regular Linux OS.  AFAIK, godaddy servers are using cPanel, and that's not supported within this Q&A site.

  You might also be running "CloudLinux".  What's the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Shared hosting with no permissions? Yet you have shell access? I'm assuming you don't have root permissions.  You might want to ask your SysAdmin or GoDaddy.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not an Ubuntu-related question, see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) – you are asking about PHP script running on CentOS on a shared hosting. Either [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), or [other Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) are better suited for this question.

Anyway, it seems you are somehow using different URLs to pull from GitHub; `git-remote-https` needs `curl` for HTTPS access. Use either SSH or Git (Read-Only) protocol, i.e. `git@github.com:user/repository.git` or `git://github.com/user/repository.git`; try changing your remote URL or cloning the repository again. Also, make sure that Git is executed in the right directory, for example add `cd /my/repo;` to the `shell_exec` command. Also, it's for the best to specify remote branch for automated pulls, i.e. `git pull origin master`.

It is possible that GoDaddy limits access of PHP scripts to certain libraries – which also affects shell scripts executed within PHP's context. If everything else fails, you may consider polling the remote repository, i.e. execute `git pull` periodically with Cron.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me @jnv. I will be more careful the next time I ask questions on stackexchange. `curl` is already installed on the server. When I try to do `git://github.com/user/repository.git`, I get an error saying that it could not connect a socket (Connection refused). I have the path of the git binary set up correctly. I think it has something to do with the dependency, may be it's not able to locate `curl`. All of the scripts are running when I execute them in the terminal after sshing into my server.

Comment: As far as establishing an `ssh connection` to the repository hosted on github is concerned. I don't have the permissions to do that. So once I ssh into my server, I cannot successfuly run `ssh git@github.com`. I get an error saying `ssh: Permission denied`. So I can only use `http` or `http(s)` solutions and I can clone repositories as I mentioed. The php script is not getting executed from the browser. That's the problem and the error I get is already posted in the question. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see; it's quite a common practice that PHP scripts are executed with different user/group, but it's also possible that `shell_exec` runs under the same account but doesn't get all environment variables to locate shared libraries for your local installation of git. You could try spawning a full shell from PHP, i.e. executing `/bin/bash -lc 'YOUR COMMAND HERE'`; also: locate `libcurl.so.3` and make sure your Git can access it – check permissions and try making a symlink in `~/git/usr/lib/` or wherever shared libraries for your local git are placed. Also, try Cron as I've noted previously.

Comment: I tried spawning a full shell from PHP like you suggested but I still get the same error. Also there is no folder called `lib` where I have git installed. Do you think that's causing the problem?

Comment: I was just assuming there may be such directory but just because it's missing isn't probably the source of problem – I don't know how exactly did you install Git. Locate the missing library and check its permissions and/or whether PHP process has an access to it. And try polling through Cron. Otherwise I recommend contacting GoDaddy support, hopefuly they know limitations of their system and will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> yum install curl
> ```
>
> I get an error that the command yum cannot be found

Are you `root`? Is is possible that your `$PATH` doesn't contain `/sbin:/usr/sbin`? Try `/sbin/yum` and `/usr/sbin/yum` to make sure that it's not a `$PATH` issue.

I'm not a CentOS expert, but if you are in fact working as `root`, and `yum` is really not installed and working, then your system may be seriously broken. As far as I know, `yum` is the default package manager of CentOS and should absolutely both exist and work.

> ```
> ~/git/usr/bin/git
> ```

That is a very strange path. It looks like you manually extracted the `git` package into your home directory?

> ```
> error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.3
> ```

Well, if you extracted the package manually, it's probably now missing the `curl` library that the `git` package depends on. You could try extracting this library too, but just putting it into your home directory won't magically make it work... you will probably need to fiddle with `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make that work, which in my experience isn't very easy.

If you can get `yum` working and then use it to install the `git package properly, it would solve this problem for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @Martin. Considering the fact that I haven't been able to resolve the issue yet, I will definitely follow your suggestions and see what I come up with.